# Como correr un proyecto de Laravel hecho en api?

Tags: php, laravel, api

Estoy intentando ver un proyecto de alguien mas hecho en Laravel, el problema es que fue hecho usando api.php y no web.php, no he podido hacer que el proyecto corra para poder revisarlo debido a que simplemente me tira un error de page not found al intentar navegar en la carpeta de public.

El usuario no ha podido ayudarme para ver su proyecto y ya he hecho todo lo que me recomendó hacer (Composer install, php artisan optimize, php artisan passport install, etc). Que podria hacer para poder ver su proyecto debido

Esta es la configuración de la .env del usuario

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:7/+q099IO7W2KMt05NBjnCaNk5De9E6oGw+bl/t0XKE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=agarciac_econnect
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Esto es lo que la persona coloco en artisan.php

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Artisan Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When we run the console application, the current CLI command will be
| executed in this console and the response sent back to a terminal
| or another output device for the developers. Here goes nothing!
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$status = $kernel->handle(
    $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
    new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Shutdown The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once Artisan has finished running, we will fire off the shutdown events
| so that any final work may be done by the application before we shut
| down the process. This is the last thing to happen to the request.
|
*/

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

El problema es que no logro entrar a las rutas encontradas en api.php que esta en la carpeta routes, simplemente me arroja un error 404 si entro a la carpeta public. Si necesitan mas información, iré mostrando a medida que me comentan

Comment: Prueba a ejecutar: **php artisan route:clear** y luego **php artisan route:list** para comprobar que las rutas estan bien configuradas. También podrías poner que contiene api.php?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que estás un poco confundido con la forma como funciona Laravel, y en general las aplicaciones web:

> Para ponerlo en términos sencillos, un API (normalmente) está diseñado para entregar (y recibir) datos en un formato que pueda interpretar otra interfaz, esto se puede hacer con muchos fines posibles, entre ellos, interactuar con varios sistemas sin modificar su naturaleza, un mejor mantenimiento/escalabilidad, etc.

En el caso de Laravel, normalmente las rutas que están en api.php no entregan (o no deberían entregar) vistas como lo hacen las de web.php, estas rutas entregan un set de datos en formato json, que son interpretados por una interfaz Front-End, algo como una UI en Vue/React/etc. o una aplicación móvil, por ejemplo.

En resumen, **revisa el formato que entrega alguno de los métodos/controladores a los que apunta una ruta de api.php**, y en cuanto al UI, es posible que esté en otro repositorio, depende como lo haya manejado quien lo creó.

Por último, para probar que las rutas estén entregando y/o recibiendo la información adecuada, puedes utilizar [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)